# If a matrix contains a differential operator, can it have eigenvalues? If yes, how can I determine them?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations, eigenfunctions

If a matrix contains a differential operator, can it have eigenvalues? If yes, how can I determine them? I will assume that the answer is yes and try to solve the following problem.

Consider the matrix $A$ defined as:

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & {d \over dx} \\1 & 0
 \end{bmatrix} \tag 1$$

The eigenvectors can be found by solving a system of equations given by:

$$ A\vec v - \lambda \vec v =0 \tag 2$$

where $\vec v$ is the eigenvector and $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue. Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be components of $\vec v$:

$$ \vec v = \begin{bmatrix}f(x)  \\g(x) 
 \end{bmatrix} \tag 3 $$

Now equation $(2)$ becomes:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}0 & {d \over dx} \\1 & 0
 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}f(x)  \\g(x) 
 \end{bmatrix} = \lambda \begin{bmatrix}f(x)  \\g(x) 
 \end{bmatrix}\tag 4$$

which is essentially the following system of equations:

$$ {d g(x) \over dx} - \lambda f(x)=0 \tag 5$$
$$ f(x) - \lambda g(x)=0 \tag 6$$

The solutions of this system of equations are:

$$ f(x) = C \lambda e^{\lambda ^2 x} \tag 7$$
$$ g(x) = C e^{\lambda ^2 x} \tag 8$$

The constant $C$ should be determined from the boundary condition. However, I don't know how to actually determine the value of $\lambda$ (assuming that it actually exists). If $A$ was a linear operator, the eigenvalues would be calculated from its determinant. But now $A$ contains a differential operator. So my question is, how can the eigenvalues of $A$ be determined?

Comment: doesn't your matrix $A$ only accept linearly dependent functions? i.e. $f = a*g$ for some $ a \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: In general the eigenvalues come from boundary conditions. With no boundary conditions, any $\lambda$ will give you an eigenfunction.

Comment: @Snared Yes actually, an answer to only linearly dependent functions would be sufficient.

Comment: To expand upon @Ian's comment, one can only ever consider about spectral properties of operators once one specifies a domain. In linear algebra, this is just some finite-dimensional vector space and is often implicit in the definition of a linear operator. When dealing with infinite-dimensional operators, e.g., operators on spaces of functions, the domain becomes more important. The same formal operator can have wildly different eigenvalues depending on the domain. For example, consider the Laplacian on $\mathbb{R}$ over 1. bounded smooth functions and 2. decaying smooth functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $v=(f,g)$ is an eigenvector for $A$. Then, there exists a $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ satisfying the equations you wrote. But
If $g'(x) = \lambda f(x)$, and $f(x) = \lambda g(x)$, then $g'(x)=\lambda^2g(x)$. Therefore there exists $\delta \in \mathbb R$ for which $g(x) = \delta \exp(\lambda^2 x)$. But that completely determines $f$. $f(x)=\lambda g(x) = \lambda \delta \exp(\lambda^2 x)$.

Pick $(\lambda, \delta) \in \mathbb R^2$. Then $(\delta \exp(\lambda^2 c) , \lambda \delta \exp(\lambda^2 x))$ are the set of eigenvectors of $A$. Which value of $\lambda$ works? All of them! $A$ has a spectrum of eigenvalues instead of finite, and in this case, any $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, even 0, with the functions $(x \mapsto 0, x \mapsto 0)$.

Comment: Thank you very much :D